# htaccess rewrite url error page and id

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to achieve the following

1. Any links like **mydomain.com/anyword** should be rewritten to index.php?pg=$1

example:

```
mydomain.com/new -->index.php?pg=new

mydomain.com/purchased -->index.php?pg=purchased

mydomain.com/login -->index.php?pg=login
```

2. Any links like **mydomain.com/anyword/anynumber** should be rewritten to index.php?pg=$1&id=$2

example:

```
mydomain.com/new/12 -->index.php?pg=new&id=12

mydomain.com/purchased/240 -->index.php?pg=purchased&id=240

mydomain.com/login/10 -->index.php?pg=login&id=10
```

I have used the following htaccess code.
The first one works properly.
Regarding the second one, the entire parameter is passed to pg and there is no parameter id at all.

That is in case of url
    mydomain.com/purchased/240 
in my php $_Get has only 'pg' parameter and 'id' parameter at all
and pg=/purchased/240

Please suggest the proper way to do it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pg=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/.*$ /index.php?pg=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

Thanks

EDIT: Correct solution in case anyone made need it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+) /index.php?pg=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?pg=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have anything to do with HTA?

Comment: @Teemu - why not ? There is some error in the rewrite rule. I tried other rules also. it is not working.

Comment: ok. found it myself. The Rewrite condition has to be repeated again for the second rule. The second rule should come first. edited the answer. Thanks to @starkeen for mentioning that the second rule should come up.

Comment: ?? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/hta/info

Comment: @teemu - you are right that this question does not relate to hta.but I don't understand why you are bringing in hta here. It is not mentioned either in question or tag. Htaccess is not hta. Google it and please find yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the catch-all pattern. **(.*)** matches everything and rewrites it to the target. For your example, your first rule matches both requests, **/foobar/** and **/foobar/123** are rewritten to **/index.php?pg=request** . To fix this, you need to fix the order of your rules, you need to put your specific rule before the catch-all rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?pg=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ((?!index.php).+) /index.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

Comment: In this case i am getting the following error: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@xl2tally.casangarnco.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: OK, i think the error was due to identical pattern and target. i have excluded the destination path in the Rule's pattern. Try the updated rule.

Comment: sorry. getting the same internal error. But if i remove the specific rule the first type of url - general rewrite works. I think there is some error in the specific rule.